# Large Google Map Area to High Pixel Image

Tags: google-maps

Here is my code to view the map. I just need to save this same view as to image file. It has large number of pixels  like width: 10000px; height: 35000px. I used several addons to take the snapshots using chrome and firefox, but due to the large number of pixels, I cannot save it. Please help me. Thank You!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Map</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 10000px; height: 35000px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var myStyle = [
       {
         featureType: "administrative",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "poi",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "water",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "off" }
         ]
       },{
         featureType: "road",
         elementType: "labels",
         stylers: [
           { visibility: "on" }
         ]
       }
     ];

     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
       mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: ['mystyle', google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN]
       },
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(6.937665, 79.946468),
       zoom: 16,
       mapTypeId: 'mystyle'
     });

     map.mapTypes.set('mystyle', new google.maps.StyledMapType(myStyle, { name: 'My Style' }));
   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `webkit2png` for this... upload your `HTML` above to a website you own, say `http://www.freddyfrog.com/map.html` then at the command line in Terminal, run

```
webkit2png -F -H 5000 -W 8000 http://www.freddyfrog.com/map.html
```

and you should get a `PNG` file called `freddyfrogcommaphtml.png` that will be 5,000 pixels high by 8,000 pixels wide. You can diddle around with the sizes and names as you wish - I am only giving an example.

The `-H` parameter is the height, in pixels. The `-W` parameter is the width, in pixels. The `-F` means output the `full-size` image only, not thumbnails.

Comment: Mark Setchell, thanks for your response, do you know how to run webkit2png in windows?

Comment: I have not tried any Windows software for this but these look hopeful... http://labnol.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/how-to-capture-save-screenshots-of.html

Comment: It's fine Mark, could you please tell me, can I use ubuntu terminal for this? it will work?

Comment: `phantomjs` may be another way of doing the same thing... http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html